# Delta Updates Api

Tags: android, api, delta

I want to implement Delta updates, and I have no clue how they work. If anyone could share some information, or tell me where I could find some, I would be very grateful.

*A delta update is an update that only requires the user to download the code that has changed, not the whole program. It can significantly save time and bandwidth. The name is drawn from the fact that the Greek letter delta, Δ or δ, is used to denote change in mathematical sciences.*

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything to utilize this feature. It is the default behavior for all apps on the Google Play Store as of Jelly Bean ([4.2, API 17](http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/)).